# How do I get the name of a form after a post request in django?

Tags: python, django

```
<form method="post" name="message_frm">{% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{post.id}}">
         {{message_frm.as_p}}
      <input type="submit" value="Reply"/
```

I just wanted to know how I can verify that the form that was sent during a POST request was a form with the name of "message_frm"

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can set `name` in name attribute of `submit` button like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Reply" name ="message_frm">
```

and in `views.py` you can recongnize `form` like this:

```
if 'message_frm' in request.POST:
    #do somethings
```

Comment: I'm looking for way to just get the name of the form from the request object. Something like request.POST.form.name

Comment: Just a quick question?, is the name of the form itself inaccessible? For example, does the data that is sent contain only what is in the "<form></form>" tags and not what is in the form tag itself?

Comment: Correct. That's just the way that HTML forms always work. See [17.13 Form Submission](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13), in particular `17.13.2 Successful controls` and `17.13.3 Processing form data`. I guess it would be handy if frameworks automagically added a hidden field or used Hasan' trick to include the form name/id in the successful controls. OTOH, it could also be annoying if they meddled with your page's structure like that. :)

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you want to check this in the view. I always do something like this to determine which form was used.

```
<form method="post" name="message_frm">{% csrf_token %}

  <-- Add this input to all forms -->
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="message_frm">

  <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{post.id}}">
     {{message_frm.as_p}}
  <input type="submit" value="Reply"/


def viewFunc(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        if name == 'message_frm':
            # Do something here.
        elif name == 'other_frm':
            # Do something else here.
```

Comment: Ooh, I like Hasan's better than mine. I'd go with that if it works for you.

Comment: Just a quick question?, is the name of the form itself inaccessible? For example, does the data that is sent contain only what is in the "<form></form>" tags and not what is in the form tag itself?

Comment: Nope. When you add the form to the template it just dumps out some basic html. There is nothing special in there that the request object reads to determine if a django from was used. You'll need to use one of these little hacks to determine what was posted.