# Can a view know the html form which POST is being received by a Django view?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a `html` file that has several forms that can be submited independently, and I have a view that receives and manages these POSTs. I submit the forms programmatically, and I need to know in the view which of the forms is the one submitted. I tried by using a `if 'form-name' in request.POST`, but it is not working.

This is the html file:

```
{% extends "StylingApp/base_site.html" %}

{% block title %} Álbumes {% endblock title %}

{% block stylesheets %}
  {{ block.super }}
{% endblock stylesheets %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="right_col" role="main">
    <div class="">
      <div class="page-title">
        <div class="title_left">
          <h3> Álbum: {{ album.name }}</h3>
          <form method="POST" name ="new-files" id="new-files" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-photos"><span class="fa fa-photo"></span> Agregar</div>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="select-photo-files" style="opacity:0" onchange="submitNewFiles()" multiple/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit-new-files" value="" style="opacity:0"/>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div class="title_right">
          <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group pull-right top_search">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar...">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Ir</button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="clearfix"></div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="x_panel">
            <div class="x_content">
              <div class="row">
                {% for photo in photos %}
                <div class="col-md-55">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="image view view-first">
                      <img style="width: 100%; display: block;" src="{{ photo.photo.url }}" alt="image" />
                      <div class="mask no-caption">
                        <div class="tools tools-bottom">
                          <a href="{{ photo.photo.url }}"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="caption">
                      <p>{{ photo.description }}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}

{% block javascripts %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var addPhotosButton = document.getElementById('add-photos');
    var selectPhotoFilesInput = document.getElementById('select-photo-files');
    var submitNewFilesInput = document.getElementById('submit-new-files');
    var newFilesForm = document.getElementById('new-files')

    addPhotosButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      selectPhotoFilesInput.click();
    });

    function submitNewFiles() {
      newFilesForm.submit();
    };
  </script>
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

And this is the view:

```
class AlbumsListView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = 'login'

    def get(self, request, album_pk=None):

        if album_pk == None:
            context = self.populate_with_user_albums(owner=request.user)
        else:
            context = self.populate_with_album_content(album_pk=album_pk)

        return render(request, 'AlbumsManagerApp/media_gallery.html', context)

    def post(self, request, album_pk):
        if 'new-files' in request.POST:
            photos = request.FILES.getlist('file')
            for photo in photos:
                new_photo = Photograph()
                new_photo.owner = request.user
                new_photo.album = Album.objects.get(id=album_pk)
                new_photo.photo = photo

                new_photo.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)

    def populate_with_user_albums(self, owner):
        albums = Album.objects.filter(owner=owner).values()

        return {
            'album_name': 'Mis Álbunes',
            'albums': albums
        }

    def populate_with_album_content(self, album_pk):
        album = Album.objects.get(id=album_pk)
        photos = album.photos_of_album.all()

        return {
            'album': album,
            'photos': photos
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Get the form name or id from template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494064/django-get-the-form-name-or-id-from-template)

Comment: I don't think so. This question is about Django Forms, and my question is about html forms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get in the name of a form after a post request in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26048602/1526703)

Comment: You are right, I have linked to the correct one now. It has some interesting ideas

Comment: Thanks, now I know that what I want is not possible. I'll try to use these hacks.